# React array mapping, toggles all drop-downs on click, I want to open the dropdown for the clicked card only

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

> **TextQuoteCard**

```
    import React, {useRef, useState} from 'react'
    import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

    import {QuoteCardDropdown} from "../../utils/dropdowns";
    
    export const TextQuoteCard = () => {
    
        const [open, setOpen] = useState(false)
        const toggle = () => setOpen(!open)
        const [textQuote, setTextQuote] = useState([
        
            {
                userId: '123',
                userName: 'Tr',
                userImageUrl: 'https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-thumb-892821828-200-lrcgeycqieflgsovvoxglqawinbcjhtv.jpeg',
                quoteId: 'TQ122',
                postDateTime: 'Fri',
                quoteAuthorId: '123',
                quoteAuthorName: 'Jhon Mart',
                quoteCategory: 'Motivational',
                quoteType: 'textQuote',
                quoteText: 'If there’s no market, about finding market opportunities, or creating opportunities. If there’s no market, then you need to grow one',
                quoteImageUrl: 'https://qph.',
                bookmarkStatus: 2,
                likesCount: 3300,
                commentsCount: 123,
                overallShareCount: 1203,
                fbShareCount: 423,
                twtShareCount: 1232,
                waShareCount: 1023,
                viewCount: 1923
            },
            {
                userId: '124',
                userName: 'nr',
                userImageUrl: 'https://qph.fi.jpeg',
                quoteId: 'TQ123',
                postDateTime: 'Fri',
                quoteAuthorId: '123',
                quoteAuthorName: 'Wall Mart',
                quoteCategory: 'Motivational',
                quoteType: 'textQuote',
                quoteText: 'Best thing to do. ',
                quoteImageUrl: '',
                bookmarkStatus: 1,
                likesCount: 3300,
                commentsCount: 123,
                overallShareCount: 1203,
                fbShareCount: 423,
                twtShareCount: 1232,
                waShareCount: 1023,
                viewCount: 1923
            }
            ])
        const handleBookmark = (event) => {
            console.log(event)
        }
        const idGetter = (id) =>{
            console.log(id)
        }
        const test = Object.keys(textQuote).map(item => item)
        console.log(test)
    
        return(
            <div>
                {
                    textQuote.map((quote) => (
                        <div className="QuoteCardPrimaryContainer" key={quote.quoteId}>
                          <div>{quote.userName}</div>
                           <div className="ddContainer">
                             <span className="QuoteCardEngagementActionButtonIconContainer">
                              <span className="QuoteCardEngagementActionButtonIcon"
                                onClick={() => toggle(!open)}
                               >
                                options
                              </span>
                             </span>                                                                           
                            {open && <QuoteCardDropdown targetLink={quote.quoteId}/>}
                           </div>
                          </div>
    
                    ))
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

**

> **QuoteCardDropdown.js**

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

import '../../global/assets/css/dropdowns.css'

export const QuoteCardDropdown = (props) => {
    const [ddItems, SetDdItems] = useState([
        {
            ddOptionIcon: 'icon',
            ddOptionText: 'Share',
            ddOptionTip: 'Tip text goes here',
            ddOptionBorder: 'no',
            targetId: props.targetId,
            targetLink: props.targetLink
        },
        {
            ddOptionIcon: 'icon',
            ddOptionText: 'Bookmark',
            ddOptionTip: 'Tip text goes here',
            ddOptionBorder: 'no',
            targetId: props.targetId,
            targetLink: props.targetLink
        }
    ])
    return (
        <div>
            <div className="quoteCardDropdownPrimaryContainer">
            
                            <div className="quoteCardDropdownPrimaryBody">
                                <div className="quoteCardDropdownPrimaryBodyInner">
                                    {
                                        ddItems.map(item => (
                                            <Link to=
                                                      {
                                                          item.ddOptionText === 'Edit this Quote' ?
                                                              `${'edit/' + props.targetLink}` :
                                                          item.ddOptionText === 'Share' ?
                                                              `${'share/' + props.targetLink}` : ''
                                                      }
                                            >
                                                <div className="quoteCardDropdownContentWrapper">
                                                    <div className="quoteCardDropdownContentItem">
                                                        <div className="quoteCardDropdownItem" key={item.ddOptionText}>
                                                            {item.ddOptionText}
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                            </Link>
                                        ))
                                    }
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div className="quoteCardPointer" data-placement='top'> </div>
          
        </div>

    )

}
```

I have array of objects mapping to which showed multiple card on-page/feed. each card has a dropdown that the user can perform several actions for the clicked card. think of FB feed or any other social media feed card that the user can click to open a dropdown and pick option for the card. I am trying to achieve something similar but the **problem** is when I click on the button to open the dropdown it toggles all the dropdowns for all the cards instead of opening the dropdown for the clicked card.

**Expected Behavior: open the dropdown for the clicked card only.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the `open` to take the id:

```js
const [open, setOpen] = useState() // undefined is nothing open
const toggle = id => setOpen(open === id ? undefined : id) // close if currently open

// the JSX

return(
  <div>
  {textQuote.map((quote) => (
        <div className="QuoteCardPrimaryContainer" key={quote.quoteId}>
          <div>{quote.userName}</div>
          <div className="ddContainer">
            <span className="QuoteCardEngagementActionButtonIconContainer">
              <span className="QuoteCardEngagementActionButtonIcon"
                onClick={() => toggle(quote.quoteId)}>
                options
                </span>
              </span>                                                                           
              {open === quote.quoteId && <QuoteCardDropdown targetLink={quote.quoteId}/>}
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Thank you, perfect.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are trying to control all dropdowns using a single state variable `open`.

```
{open && <QuoteCardDropdown targetLink={quote.quoteId}/>}
```

When you click on any dropdown it will toggles `open` and then all dropdowns will open because that single variable controls all of them.
Instead, what you can do is maintain a separate state variable for each dropdown.
I have an example to maintain separate state variable for dropdown-

```
toggle = (index) => {
   this.setState(prevState => { 
          [`open+${index}`]: !prevState[`open${index}`] 
          } 
}
```

This way you can keep track of/or toggles `open` for particular dropdown you just need to change below code -

```
{
 textQuote.map((quote, index) => (   //add 2nd parameter as index
    <div className="QuoteCardPrimaryContainer" key={quote.quoteId}>
         <div>{quote.userName}</div>
             <div className="ddContainer">
                <span className="QuoteCardEngagementActionButtonIconContainer">
                    <span className="QuoteCardEngagementActionButtonIcon"
                           onClick={() => this.toggle(index)}
                            >
                             options
                     </span>
                  </span>                                                                           
                { this.state[`open${index}`] && <QuoteCardDropdown targetLink={quote.quoteId}/>}
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
   ))
}
```

Note - Unfortunately I am not aware of handling state as dynamically inside the function component, but I have given you the exact same use case using class component.

Comment: Thanks for replying, I mapping through an array of objects so how do control separate state for each? that is the problem. how to open the dropdown based on the index number of the clicked object.

Comment: I have updated the answer, but for that, you need to convert your function component to the class component.

Answer (score 0):

Use an object indexed by quote ID to track a card's open status by the quote ID. I copied only the relevant code, make sure this has all of the other code you need:

```js
export const TextQuoteCard = () => {
  const [openById, setOpenById] = useState({});
  const toggle = (quoteId) => {
    setOpenById((currOpenById) => {
      const nextOpenById = { ...currOpenById };
      if (currOpenById[quoteId]) {
        delete nextOpenById;
      } else {
        nextOpenById[quoteId] = true;
      }
      return nextOpenById
    })
  }
  
  // ...removed code not relevant to example

  return (
    <div>
      {textQuote.map((quote) => (
        <div className="QuoteCardPrimaryContainer" key={quote.quoteId}>
          <div>{quote.userName}</div>
          <div className="ddContainer">
            <span className="QuoteCardEngagementActionButtonIconContainer">
              <span
                className="QuoteCardEngagementActionButtonIcon"
                onClick={() => toggle(quote.quoteId)}
              >
                options
              </span>
            </span>
            {openById[quote.quoteId] && <QuoteCardDropdown targetLink={quote.quoteId} />}
          </div>
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};
```